# Automatically set local IP Address in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm devolping an android app that heavily uses Rest Services.
For developing and debugging, I run the Rest server locally (on my notebook). At home, I have static IP Adresses and therefore, I can put
a static String in my build.gradle.
But if I work from somewhere else, I always have to check my notebook's ip address and edit my build.gradle.

Now I'm curious: Is there a way to insert the current local IP address into my build.gradle automatically?

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
            resValue "string", "host_name", "192.168.0.102" // <--- should be set automatically
        }
        release {
            ...
            resValue "string", "host_name", "example.com/rest/"
        }
}
```

Comment: Since Gradle is Groovy, if you can figure out Groovy code to find your local IP address, you could use that value in your `resValue` statement: http://blog.digital-morphosis.com/2010/06/getting-ip-addresses-of-local-machine.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use Groovy methods to find the local IP address:

```
resValue "string", "host_name", InetAddress.localHost.canonicalHostName
```

Alternatively you also could use `hostAddress` instead of `canonicalHostName`.

Comment: should be written like this : buildConfigField 'String', 'IP_LOCAL_SERVER', "\"${InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress}\""

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding an awser because I'll probably need this in the future

In build.graddle of the project add into default config the buildConfigField line :

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.foo.bar"
    minSdkVersion 25
    targetSdkVersion 25
    buildConfigField 'String', 'IP_LOCAL_SERVER', "\"${InetAddress.localHost.hostAddress}\""
}
```

Then in you code you can call

`localIP = BuildConfig.IP_LOCAL_SERVER;`

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Unfortunately for me it returns 127.0.0.1 :/

Comment: It was running on a windows machine, if that changes something, since I don't have access to this project anymore I can't run tests sorry, but it was working for us.